# XML attribute to POCO class with RestSharp deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, rest, restsharp

I have a response that following :

```
<CONTENT>
      <SEND_SMS_SUCCESS>
         <TRANSACTION id="30911386"/>
         <VALID_SMS_COUNT>2</VALID_SMS_COUNT>
         <INVALID_SMS_COUNT>0</INVALID_SMS_COUNT>
      </SEND_SMS_SUCCESS>
</CONTENT>
```

and my class:

```
public class CONTENT
{
    public SEND_SMS_SUCCESS SEND_SMS_SUCCESS  { get; set; }
}

public class SEND_SMS_SUCCESS
{
    [XmlElement("TRANSACTION")]
    public TRANSACTION TRANSACTION { get; set; }
    public int VALID_SMS_COUNT { get; set; }
    public int INVALID_SMS_COUNT { get; set; }
}
public struct TRANSACTION
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

}
```

I am using RestSharp:

```
var response = client.Execute<CONTENT>(request);
```

but I can't get Transaction.ID .It's value is null. How can I get this attribute?

Comment: Try making `TRANSACTION` a class

Comment: Transaction does not have a value.  It has an attribute ID.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya there was no change

Comment: According to [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36894380/215552) and [the documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization), it appears you need to use `DeserializeAs`, not `XmlElement`/`XmlAttribute`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I changed  [XmlAttribute("id")] to [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")] and it worked! Please type as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed XmlAttribute and XmlElement and added Deserialize attribute:

```
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
```